# How to create a gauge chart which takes mouse/touch to change the needle value

Tags: html, charts, highcharts, html5-canvas

How to create an interactive chart where user clicks on needle of gauge and the value changes as mouse is dragged (or swiped from phone).
Is there any charts for that like highcharts( or any canvas related example is welcome )

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I've an example here: jsfiddle.net/JdLUw , where on mouse click the needle of the gauge moves, how can i change it to mouse drag,i.e, the needle should change till the mouse is dragged.